# Azure Function QueueTrigger and int message

Tags: c#, azure-functions, message-queue, azure-queues, queuetrigger

I want to save int value to queue message and then get it on Azure Function QueueTrigger.

I save by the following way:

```
        int deviceId = -1;
        await queue.AddMessageAsync(new CloudQueueMessage(deviceId.ToString()));
```

and then listen queue:

```
    public async Task Run(
        [QueueTrigger("verizon-suspend-device", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")] string queueMessage, 
        ILogger log)
    {
        int deviceId = int.Parse(queueMessage);
```

but all messages are being moved to `verizon-suspend-device-poison` queue. What is wrong?

Comment: a LOT of things can be wrong. Message goes to poison if it 3 retries fail (3 is default). You need to read/post the exception/error messages of what happened during those 3 executions. Also 1) remove `int.Parse(queueMessage)` and just add a log, see what/if-anything are you getting into the Function. 2) Put the whole code of Function inside a try-catch and print exception. Best place to look for exceptions/errors (especially the ones outside your code) is Portal->Functions->your-function->Monitor

Comment: it's not logged at all, even when I try to log `queueMessage`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an unfortunate limitation that [Azure Function Queue Triggers currently require Base64-encoded messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=csharp). If you run your code against the storage emulator you should see an exception from your trigger like `The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.`

For now, at least (i.e., until the trigger can handle binary/utf8 messages), queueing code has to place messages on the queues as Base64 strings. The queue trigger code for a `string` message ends up [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/27c78f26917a963169a18f1501fa22ce1ba6f9a4/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage/Queues/Triggers/StorageQueueMessageToStringConverter.cs#L19), and [`AsString` assumes a Base64 encoding](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/631).

For that [(old) version of the storage SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue/), you can send a Base64-encoded UTF-8 string representation of the integer:

```
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(deviceId.ToString());
await queue.AddMessageAsync(new CloudQueueMessage(Convert.ToBase64String(bytes), isBase64Encoded: true));
```

With the [new storage SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Queues/), you would [set `MessageEncoding` on your `QueueClient` to `QueueMessageEncoding.Base64`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/be7acee5bf7432a09daa3f06568e04a5d31e5059/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Queues/README.md#message-encoding) and then just send the string representation of the integer (the new storage SDK will UTF-8 encode and then Base64-encode for you).